# A rational homology $\Bbb CP^2$ is a rational cohomology $\Bbb CP^2$

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, complex-geometry, projective-space

Let $S$ be a normal projective complex surface. $S$ is called a rational homology $\Bbb CP^2$ if $H_i(S,\Bbb Q)=H_i(\Bbb CP^2,\Bbb Q)$ for all $i$, and $S$ is called a rational cohomology $\Bbb CP^2$ if $H^*(S,\Bbb Q)=H^*(\Bbb CP^2,\Bbb Q)$. Clearly a rational cohomology $\Bbb CP^2$ is a rational homology $\Bbb CP^2$ by the universal coefficient theorem. Is the converse also true?

Again by the universal coefficient theorem, for $S$ a rational homology $\Bbb CP^2$, we have $H^i(S,\Bbb Q)=H^i(\Bbb CP^2,\Bbb Q)$ for all $i$, but we have to consider the product structure of the cohomology ring. Maybe the condition that $S$ is projective can be useful, but I got stuck.

Comment: Over $\mathbb{Q}$ (and more generally a field), the homology groups form a coalgebra, and this coalgebra [is dual to the algebra structure of cohomology](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/415/does-homology-have-a-coproduct/418#418). So if "rational homology $\mathbb{C}P^2$" means the homology is isomorphic to $H_*(\mathbb{C}P^2,\mathbb{Q})$ as a coalgebra and "rational cohomology $\mathbb{C}P^2$" means the cohomology is isomorphic to $H^*(\mathbb{C}P^2,\mathbb{Q})$, it seems to work out.